# How to put the formula in line with the text in the example below

Tags: arrays

```
Be the $
\begin{array}{cccl}
\gamma\ : & \! \mathrm{I} & \! \longrightarrow & \! \mathbb{R}^2 \\
& \! s & \! \longmapsto & \! \gamma(s)
\end{array}
$ differentiable and parameterized
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Do you mean that the first line in the `array` should be vertically aligned with the text?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\begin{array}[t]`, but the result won't be pretty. The intercolumn spacing should be removed and just an empty group inserted at the point of alignment. I'd use `\to` (equivalent to `\rightarrow`) and `\mapsto` instead of the `long` variants that just waste space.

There is no added clarity in adding the action of the map below the domain and codomain, with the additional effect of leaving a huge space between lines. Such a form should be used only in displays.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

Let $\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}>{{}}l@{}}
  \gamma\colon I &\to \mathbb{R}^{2}\\
               s &\mapsto \gamma(s)
\end{array}$
be differentiable and parameterized
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

When inline, I'd simply typeset the two parts one after the other:

```
Let $\gamma\colon I \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$, $s \mapsto \gamma(s)$,
be differentiable and parameterized
```

[image]

In the specific case, I find that `s\mapsto\gamma(s)` adds *no* information, as it's standard notation, so in my document I'd simply write

```
Let $\gamma\colon I \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be differentiable and parameterized
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can (i) take the term `$\gamma$` out of the `array` environment and (ii) reduce the value of the parameter `\arraycolsep`, which governs the amount of intercolumn white space used in arrays, to something like `2pt`; the default value is `5pt`.

For the sake of keeping the MWE simple, the resetting of `\arraycolsep` is given global scope. If you find yourself using `array` environments elsewhere in the document, you should make the resetting of `\arraycolsep` *local* to the formula at hand, say, by moving the instruction `\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}` to just after the opening `$` symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\begin{document}
Be the $\gamma:
\begin{array}{rcl}
    \mathrm{I} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R}^2 \\
    s          & \longmapsto     & \gamma(s)
\end{array}$ 
differentiable and parameterized \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that globally changing `\arraycolsep` is a good idea. You should do it in the formula, just after the opening `$`.

Comment: @egreg -- I did it mostly to keep the MWE as simple as possible. I've added a paragraph explaining how the reset might be kept local to the formula at hand.